# Change an attribute of an object using value of input tag?

Tags: javascript, forms, object, input, styles

I'm trying to change the value of a specific object only, but the value is grabbed out of an input tag which I'm using  `getElementById()` .
I get an error stating I cannot call  `getElementById()`  of undefined

```
interfaces[idx].document.getElementById(panel).style.fontSize = document.getElementById('fsizes').value +'px';
```

and

```
document.getElementById(panel).style.fontSize = interfaces[idx].document.getElementById('fsizes').value +'px';
```

both don't seem to work.

```
<input type="text" name="fsize" id = 'fsizes' onchange = 'changeSize();'/>
```

This is the input.

---

edit:panel gets its value when one of the spans gets clicked so I know which panel's attribute I'm changing. The panels on my page are part of one object.
Interfaces is the array of my object. idx is which object is being accessed.

Comment: What's in "panel"? How does it get its value?  When you call `document.getElementById()`, you **never** have to qualify it unless you've got lots of frames or something. (What is "interfaces"?)

Comment: Then `interfaces[idx].document` must be null. The problem is elsewhere -- probably where you attempt to define `interfaces[idx].document`.

Comment: See my answer below.  If everything is on the same page and there are no the elements are not in iframes, you do not need to prefix the document object with your interfaces array.  document is a reference to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/adCE6/  fsizes returns a value when I set a default, guessing that panel is undefined.  If you have it set somewhere make sure the scope is correct, prefix it with var if it's not already there.  or if panel is not a variable enclose it in parenthesis.

Comment: I have it that panel has a default value so it's always defined. What do you mean by scope?

Comment: I saw your code here and panel is blank  panel = "".   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865970/cannot-set-read-property-of-undefined  by scope I meant if panel is being declared in a function but it doesn't look to be.

Comment: Oh wow I didn't see that. I made it so panel doesnt equal "", but it still wouldnt function.

Comment: check to make sure that panel = the id of an element in the dom.  If it's still not working post a new fiddle and we can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine if you drop the interfaces[idx].  See the following example http://jsfiddle.net/uX5sW/3/

Comment: The problem is I need to be able to differentiate which object is changing because I'm trying to change just 1 object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865970/cannot-set-read-property-of-undefined my entire code is up on this question

Comment: You can simply pass the variables that you need to the function in the event declaration.  For example onchange="changeSize(this);" or onchange="changeSize('<element id>')".  Similarly you can do this for the changeColor function.  You can simply pass the color instead of setting the interface color.